# Trying to create a login using PHP

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

Putting aside the SQL Injection and other security issues I am having a problem trying to get the following piece of code to work. I know I am close but cannot figure out how to do it. Currently I am receiving this error message:

"Successful Connection
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proper\checklogin.php on line 30
wrong username/password"

Checklogin.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();


    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die ('No connection');
    print "Successful Connection";
    mysqli_select_db($conn , 'ssssg3') or die ('database will not open');

    // username and password sent from form
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM log_in_info where email=$email";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  

    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);


    if ($row['password'] == $password) {
    header('location:main1.php');
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo 'wrong username/password';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Probably the `$result` is `FALSE` as query failed.

Comment: @rid I believe he said that he will address the security concerns once he's got the basic concept down...though I agree, it should be incorporated from the get-go, so it won't be forgotten.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM log_in_info where email=$email";
```

This is where your error rests. Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM log_in_info where email='$email'";
```

The query fails, because you need to put literals into ' '.
Be sure to check the return value of `mysqli_query` and use `mysqli_error` to determine the actual error message.

To do some proper error checking I suggest (assuming that `$email` is properly escaped)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM log_in_info where email='$email'";
if(!$sql) die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: @rid Yes, for this example I assumed that the string had been properly escaped.

Comment: Thankyou, it's always the silly mistakes that still seem to get me everytime!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, it's not Error message. "Undefined index: password" means, what you accessing array key,  what not exists. To avoid id you can use some like this (for you code):

```
if (array_key_exists( 'password', $row ) and $row['password'] === $password) {
```